# How can I execute Legacy Scala Code Base in Databricks with pyspark

Tags: scala, pyspark, databricks

I have a number of legacy scala packages/ code base that needs to be migrated to Databricks.

Currently, these scala packages are translated to jar files which are invoked from a shell script.

I can run scala in Databricks, but how can I call a package file/ scala code base within pyspark? Is that possible, if so how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate them 1:1, then you just need to run them as a Jar task or Spark Submit task in [Databricks Workflows](https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/jobs/jobs.html#create-a-job).  Wrapping them as PySpark makes no sense from my point of view, until you provide more information what do you mean by that.